# AudioKit - can't get AKClipRecorder working

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I am trying to achieve the ability to record something (microphone or oscillator or any other input), I need it to be as accurate as it could be in terms of executing a callback right after recording finishes, so I thought ClipRecorder could help me here. this piece of code goes into a simple view controller's `viewDidLoad` function, and the code executed and get to the end but the callback of the clip recorder never executed.

Can you please advise me what did I do wrong? I am very new to AudioKit so it could be my miss-understanding of things. here is the code:

```
AKSettings.bufferLength = .shortest
AKSettings.defaultToSpeaker = true
try! AKSettings.setSession(category: .playAndRecord)

let oscillator = AKOscillator()
let oscMixer = AKMixer(oscillator)
AudioKit.output = oscMixer
AudioKit.start()

oscillator.start()

let clipRecorder = AKClipRecorder(node: oscMixer)

do{
    AKLog("1")
    try clipRecorder.recordClip(time: 0, duration: 2, tap: nil, completion: { url, something, err in
        AKLog("recorded clip")
        oscillator.stop()
    })
    AKLog("2")
} catch let error as ClipRecordingError {
    print("\(String(describing: error.errorDescription))")
} catch {
    print("something general")
}
```

logs 1,2 are printed, 'recorded clip' is not printed.

many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call clipRecorder.play() or clipRecorder.play(at:).

Comment: Hi, I cannot see any start function on the AKClipRecorder API, http://audiokit.io/docs/Classes/AKClipRecorder.html. *edit:* oh! now I see it has the play function, well that is really confusing, I thought play function should start playing the AKClipRecorder, it should really be called start. (please edit your answer so I will accept it)

Comment: It is a little confusing, "play" implies that the recorder would play audio.  Should have been called start.